# How to convert CDR to ASCII using Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1

i am trying to decode AIR (account information and refill) record to using ASN.1
i have tried using bouncy castle but it converts only the first field of the record and it does not loop to the next fields in the records

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObjectParser;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERTaggedObject;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.ASN1Dump;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class Tag {
    private ASN1InputStream bIn;
    public boolean isend;

    public void tagReader(byte[] f) throws IOException {
        bIn = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(f));
        DERTaggedObject callEventRecord = (DERTaggedObject) bIn.readObject();
        DLSequence sgsnPDPRecord = (DLSequence) callEventRecord.getObject();

        System.out.println("TAG OUTPUT");
        for (int i = 0; i < sgsnPDPRecord.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("size " + sgsnPDPRecord.size());
            ASN1Encodable seq = sgsnPDPRecord.getObjectAt(i);

            System.out.println("SEQUENCE \n" + ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(seq, true));
        }
        DERTaggedObject obj = (DERTaggedObject) sgsnPDPRecord.getObjectAt(0);
        for (int x = 0; x < obj.getTagNo(); x++) {

            System.out.println("tag \n" + callEventRecord.getTagNo());
            System.out.println("obj \n" + callEventRecord.getObject());
            byte[] b = callEventRecord.getObject().getEncoded();
            System.out.println("obj string \n" + Hex.toHexString(b).toString()); // CallEventRecordType
            System.out.println("size " + sgsnPDPRecord.size());

        }
```

how can i loop in the fields of the record and output them all

Comment: *...AIR (account information and refill)...*. I don't know what that is and without the ASN.1 for that we can't help you.

Comment: Account information and refill  records  are the detail record produced from the charging system in telecommunications

Comment: It is originally binary and are encoded using ASN.1 it consists of many fields for many users of the telecom company we convert it to ascii but only one record for single user we need to know what can we do to make the for loop goes through all the records

Comment: *...encoded using ASN.1...* This is incorrect terminology. ASN.1 defines several encoding schemes e.g. DER, BER, XER, etc. You should already know what the ASN.1 module says before you can attempt to decode data into it. There are ASN.1 compilers that will automatically produce encoding and decoding routines from an ASN.1 module.